# Need help trying to figure out the tuning / chords of a live acoustic performance of "Two is Better Than One" by Boys Like Girls

Tags: rock, pop, live-music

The song is called "Two is better than One" and the live performance is very nice and different from the original record, been trying to learn it so I can use it during a wedding. However I can't figure out the chords or tuning that the guy is playing, can anyone with a better ear (or eye) figure it out.

Even if it's not the whole thing, just parts so I can get a start and figure out the rest myself. I can't seem to figure out even a single chord, and this doesn't usually happen. Im wondering if it's because they are using strange chords or just very abnormal tuning (I tried standard, half step down, drop D).

Examples of the live performances:

[example 1, the chords presses are not so clear here but there are a few close up shots. The sound and tuning is more clear in this video however. Song starts a few seconds into the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcHCClCYZ_Q)

[example 2, the chords presses are clearer at certain angles. Song starts at 3:50](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtGL53033Hg)

There are more on youtube, just search "two is better than one live".

And for all of these forget about the background tabs that the other guy is playing, just focus on the chords of the guy who is singing (that's the main melody).

I really hope someone is able to help, I'm been scratching my head for sessions of trying to figure this out now. Figured someone with more experience might be able to help much faster.

Edit: It's also ok if you share one finding on the whole thing, you don't need to solve the entire song or tuning. At this point I just need anything to help so I can start figuring this out.. I tried a bunch of tunings and nothing sounds right..

Answer (score 4):

This is all standard stuff except for the fact that it's in B.

They're adding some extra notes to the chords but the basic changes are

```
B B G#m G#m E F# B B
B B G#m G#m E F# B B
E E F# F# E E F# F# E E F# F# 
G#m F# E E G# F# B B
etc.
```

It looks like they might be using some non-standard tuning, but I'll leave that up to the guitar specialists.

Comment: Thanks fo rthis, but yeah I really want to play it the way they do it. Because this matches the melody but it doesnt sound exactly the same, especially when picking with a pick like they are. Strumming sounds nearly identical however.